# Unity AddRelativeForce lock axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a top down camera with variable rotation. I'm trying to implement a pan gesture so that camera moves within x,z plane in the world space. I'm using AddRelativeForce and it works nice but has an undesired side effect of zooming. I fixed this by changing velocity after adding force (velocity.y=0). This works fine but feels a bit dirty to do in 2 steps. It also requires some plumbing to honor y velocity originating from other sources.

So my question is: can this be simplified/improved?

```
Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
rb.AddRelativeForce(new Vector3(-panGesture.DeltaX, 0, -panGesture.DeltaY) * Speed, ForceMode.Impulse);
rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, 0, rb.velocity.z);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `transform.TransformDirection` to make the conversion from relative to world, then remove the `y` component of the world force. Finally, you can then use `rb.AddForce` instead of `rib.AddRelativeForce`:

```
Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
Vector3 relativeForceVec = new Vector3(-panGesture.DeltaX, 0f, -panGesture.DeltaY) * Speed;
Vector3 worldForceVec = transform.TransformDirection(relativeForceVec);
rb.AddForce(Vector3.Scale(worldForceVec, new Vector3(1f, 0f, 1f)), ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Comment: Thanks, works great except that I get an error that operator * can not be applied to Vector3 and Vector3. Fixed by using Vector3.Scale:

`rb.AddForce(Vector3.Scale(worldForceVec, new Vector3(1f, 0f, 1f)), ForceMode.Impulse);`

Comment: @Fuczak Great! and thanks for the fix, that's what I get for doing shader code right before answering this :p